# Heroku commands not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a project built using ruby on rails. I am trying to deploy my application to Heroku but I keep getting a strange error when I try run `heroku login`.

```
!     Error parsing C:\tools\ruby24\ssl\README-SSL.md
!     Error parsing C:\tools\ruby24\ssl\README-SSL.md
!     Error parsing C:\tools\ruby24\ssl\README-SSL.md
!     Error parsing C:\tools\ruby24\ssl\README-SSL.md
!     EISDIR: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

Anyone any ideas what it could be?

I have the  Heroku Command Line Interface (CLI) installed.

**Ruby Version**: 2.4

**Rails Version**: 5.0.2

Comment: Do you have your app under version control with git?

Comment: Yes I am using git. The first part of the error is gone, now it just shows `!     EISDIR: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read` I think the problem is with Heroku because I am trying to deploy an angular application to Heroku and I am getting the same error. I uninstall the Heroku CLI and reinstalled it but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the same error; in my case, I had accidentally (via Docker volume sharing) created a directory named `.netrc` in my container's home directory. The error happens because Heroku CLI looks for a *file* at `~/.netrc` in which to store login credentials.

From https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication#api-token-storage :

> The Heroku command-line tool stores API tokens in the standard Unix file ~/.netrc ($HOME_netrc on Windows).